# convert list (from web service) to datatable c#

Tags: c#, list, wcf, datatable, listcontrol

I'm calling WCF Service that gives me a list of customers with specified field names in the BAL. I created a method `ToDataTable` as instructed on many forums (it might be wrong for this instance). I use it to convert the list into a datatable but there is a challenge that I'm facing. The error says 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable to mHotRes.DesktopPresentation.ListFrm.ListType'.

Here is my code for binding data:

```
private void BindData()
    {
        try
        {
            switch (_ListType)
            {
                case ListType.Customers:
                    IHotRes res = new MHotServiceProvider().Service;
                     List<Customer> customer = res.CustomerSaveDataList();

                    _ListType = ToDataTable(customer); //the problem occurs here
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for `ToDataTable` method:

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                //inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```

If any more code samples are needed let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reflection ToDataTable code is working correctly:

```
_ListType = ToDataTable(customer); //the problem occurs here
```

The problem is that the `_ListType` have different type from `DataTable`.

You should change the line to

```
DataTable tbl = ToDataTable(customer);//Your method returns DataTable
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work for now. I will try to display the data on the datagridview.

Comment: When I try to initialize it at the form load it says `Object Reference not set to an instance of an object`? could you guide me on this please?

Comment: @UZIERSKI this is different question, you can ask them in new one. In this case more people can help. This exception is happening, because some of your values are null. Debug it and see exactly which one.